# get active directory user passwords (unicodePwd)

Tags: python, ldap

Trying to get all users defined in active directory. Below is the script used:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ldap
import sys

# Connection information
host = 'ldap://' + server + ':' + str(port)
user = 'user'
pw = 'password'

# Init
conn = ldap.initialize( host )


try:
    # Try and make a synchronous bind
    conn.simple_bind_s( user, pw )

    # Search information
    basedn = "DC=example,DC=com"
    scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=ssheth))"
    attributes = ['*']

    # Search!
    result = conn.search_s( basedn, scope, filter, attributes )

    for v in result[0]:
        if type(v) == dict:
            for k,v in v.items():
                print k,v
        else:
            print(v)

except ldap.LDAPError as e:
    raise
```

I get the below output, but I do not see the user's password information. Is there anyway I can retrieve the unicodePwd attribute?

```
CN=ssheth,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
primaryGroupID ['513']
logonCount ['0']
cn ['ssheth']
countryCode ['0']
dSCorePropagationData ['16010101000000.0Z']
objectClass ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user']
instanceType ['4']
distinguishedName ['CN=ssheth,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com']
sAMAccountType ['805306368']
objectSid ['\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x15\x00\x00\x00\x9bR\xb2U\xef\xdac\x0c\xc9 \xe8*/\x05\x00\x00']
whenCreated ['20140226205355.0Z']
uSNCreated ['13506']
lockoutTime ['0']
badPasswordTime ['130380073014920000']
pwdLastSet ['130380192482330000']
sAMAccountName ['ssheth']
objectCategory ['CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com']
objectGUID ['\xd5\xb6\x94\x85f\x12\xb2E\xb5\xe9$\xd7\x0f\x85\xcf]']
whenChanged ['20140228000048.0Z']
badPwdCount ['0']
accountExpires ['9223372036854775807']
name ['ssheth']
codePage ['0']
userAccountControl ['544']
lastLogon ['0']
uSNChanged ['14365']
givenName ['ssheth']
lastLogoff ['0']
```

Comment: It would help if you explained _why_ you want to read the password values. There's probably another solution to your underlying problem.

Comment: we have a setup wherein the users are provisioned in AD. The linux servers need to allow authentication for users provisioned in AD. I am looking at SASL passthrough authetication as well for accomplishing this. Do you have any ideas on how best we can get this to work?

Comment: Check my second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has a pluggable authentication infrastructure called PAM.

Based on your comment, the solution is to use `pam_ldap` to allow AD users to log into Linux with their AD username and password. See http://www.padl.com/OSS/pam_ldap.html for the docs, this is a standard feature on most distributions.

The next step would be SSO. If you want single-sign-on with AD that can be arranged with Kerberos and the `pam_krb5` module. This can be tricky to set up but there is plenty of documentation.

It all depends a little on your Linux distribution, but here's an example for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto

The big professional Linuxes like RHEL and SLES have good guides and even wizards for this stuff as well.

Comment: Thanks a bunch...that should get me going in the right direction. Accepting your answer..

Comment: Hi, cog_n1t1v3
I need to get accounts/passwrds from AD to update another app for authentication, can you please let me know how to fetch password of each account in AD with Python?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @David, this question is 9 years old. But to give you a quick response: it is not possible to read passwords from AD via LDAP. If you want to do this, you have to write a password filter for the DCs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/password-filters

Answer (score 2):

You searched with an attribute filter that should match all attributes. Most LDAP servers(AD included) don't allow you to directly query the password after binding without special privileges. In other words, your code is correct, but most likely the server is not returning password attributes for searches performed by the user you are bound as.

From the AD documentation:

"The unicodePwd attribute is never returned by an LDAP search".

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx

Comment: I am connecting as a admin to active directory - still not able to retrieve the unicodePwd attribute. Is there anything that needs to be done differently here or any changes in AD config?

Comment: I updated my answer with a citation from the the documentation. It appears AD does not support what you are asking for.

Comment: so is there any way of populating openldap with AD contents?

Comment: Yes definitely, not a question for stackoverflow however. Try serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (and should not) retrieve passwords from AD (or any other LDAP server).

If you want to authenticate users, use a bind operation.

If you want to synchronize passwords, for AD you need a password filter on the DCs.